# HTTP POST Request with XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I am looking to make HTTP POST Request with XML payload.

I have looked at this documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Here the parameter `data` is I believe I should be interested in.

However, it is not entirely very clear to me how do I specify the format of this `data` parameter. In most of my earlier experience this parameter is  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

However, my request has an XML payload.

Any pointers ?

Comment: Any code that would narrow down the amount of possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.post` is a shorthand function that covers some common usecases but has some unchangeable defaults. Use [the `$.ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead. It allows you to set the content type for the request.

> ```
> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
> ```
>
> Type: String
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`, which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to `$.ajax()`, then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). The W3C
>   XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always
>   UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change
>   the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can post XML data as

```
$.ajax({
url: ajaxurl,
data: "<test><node1></node1></test>", 
type: 'POST',
contentType: "text/xml",
dataType: "text",
success : parse,
error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
    console.log(xhr.status);          
    console.log(thrownError);
} });
```